# Streaming API with Rails not able to get streamed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, twitter, streaming, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to fetch data from Twitter Streaming API in my rails app and i have created my own module which gives me `twitter Authorization Head`. I am able to get authorized but i am not getting the response back... all i see is the request in `pending` state (i am guessing as its streaming and connection not being closed). What can i do to my below code so that i can start printing the response as i get from Streaming API ?

```
    class MainController < ApplicationController
      include Oauth::Keys

      def show
        @oauth_signature_string = Oauth::Signature.generate(signature_params)
        @header                 = Oauth::HeaderString.create(header_params)

        RestClient::Request.execute(method: :GET, url: 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json', :headers => {:Authorization => %Q(OAuth ****************************)} )

      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Twitter is "streaming" the data and not closing the connection, your `RestClient` request is not being ended and your `show` action is hanging there and not "finishing". So, rails can't continue and render the default `main/show.html.erb` page.

So, you might want to look into [`ActionController::Streaming`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html) class and see if you can rewrite you views and HTTP call to utilize it. Or, it would be much easier to use a non-streaming API edge.

Also, what you are doing seems to be a better fit for javascript. You might want to use Twitter's official Javascript api to do all authentications and status streams.

Comment: hey @Uzbekjon ..i tried with `render stream: true` also. But no luck. Can you point out any example or tweak to my code

Comment: It isn't just about adding `stream: true`. You have to change your views as well. The link in my answer explains and provides examples. I would recommend just sticking to non-streaming API edge.

Comment: i am sorry for novice question but what is non-streaming API edge ? any link to it ? Or you are just mentioning like REST api ?

Comment: Yeap, I mean REST api.